# Retrieving Contract instance from .abi and address

Tags: contract-development, web3.py

Having the .abi file and the address of a Smart Contract. Can I somehow retrieve the smart contract object instance?

I know for the web3.js we could do something like:

```
var inst = eth.contract(abi).at(address))
```

But this doesn't work for the web3py. I am new to this syntax. How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:

```
contract = web3.eth.contract(abi=abi,address=address)
```

See the official documentation [here](https://web3py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/web3.eth.html#contracts).

Answer (score 1):

Calling [`web3.eth.contract`](https://web3py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/web3.eth.html#web3.eth.Eth.contract) in `web3.py` uses the following syntax:

```py
from web3 import Web3

w3 = Web3()

# modify these values
abi = {}
address = "0x00..."

contract = w3.eth.contract(address=address, abi=abi)
```

The returned value is a [`Contract`](https://web3py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/contracts.html#web3.contract.Contract) object.